# Soloing Sunwell with a Rogue

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I would like to know if there are any good ways of soloing Sunwell Raid as a Rogue. I gave it a try yesterday, but got bashed by Brutallus. This seems strange as I can solo BlackTemple relatively easily.

I would like to farm Tho'Ridal, the Legendary Bow.

So, how can a Rogue solo Brutallus?

Comment: kalecgos requires 2 groups damaging him (one inside the portal, one outside) and it's the first boss, brutallus has that stacking debuff (saw a hunter tanking him with pet), all the other bosses can be soloed. not sure you can advance past kalecgos without killing brutallus (kalecgos is skippable, don't know how)

Comment: Yeah, the part with Kalecgos can be skipped, either by stealthing or, when in Combat by reset via Vanish, but how to advance past Brutallus?

Comment: After Kale, no other boss can be skipped

Comment: I'm not sure why you think being able to solo Black Temple means Brutallus should be easy - tank swap fights are often harder to solo, and Brut was absolutely *punishing* as current content. :P

Comment: It just seemed strange to me because my Rogue got killed by Brutallus soooo hard, he did die to death! D: But I still would like to solo him to kill the rest of the Bosses :)

Comment: Yeah. Back in the day, that's more or less what he did to our tanks that would eat Shears from Illidan out of boredom. Working as intended. :P

Comment: Brutallus is _brutal_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously this fight is much easier if you aren't tanking. So go get a tank! The [Terracotta Fragment](http://www.wowhead.com/item=86572) trinket summons a mogu [Terracotta Warrior](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=65024) tank which will easily hold aggro. [One rogue reported on Wowhead](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=24882#comments:id=1774658) using it successfully on Brutallus, getting him down to 50% before the tank died and then blowing all cooldowns to finish him off.

Terracotta Fragment drops from the rare [Jonn-Dar](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=50351) in Valley of the Four Winds. He can be found in Torjari Pit, the ruins between Nesingwary's Safari and Stoneplow. This trinket is usable by all classes, so it should make it possible for any DPS spec to solo this fight.

Comment: COnfirmed, it works after the second meteor, I used the trinket and survided brutallus :) thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible for some classes(also very dependent on the player) to solo Brutallus currently. The only ones that would have a chance at it are those that have extremely high sustained damage (70-80k dps in current tier) or those that can survive long enough while putting out around 30-40k dps.

Currently the best classes for soloing Brutallus are DK/Paladin/Druid/Hunter/Warlock/Warrior in that order. The reason for this is they either have decent damage with good healing capabilities in tank spec or they have a pet that can tank the boss until the  stacks kill the pet(which by that time the boss should be dead).

Since a Rogue has no way to drop the stacks from the bosses debuff, and no major healing abilities, you would need to pull that 70-80k sustained DPS to even have a chance at downing him. In this case, it depends more on the player and their gear than what class/spec you play as.

So in conclusion, yes it is possible for a Rogue to solo Brutallus, but a large majority of rogue players will not be capable of it.

Comment: also, if all you want to do is kill him so that you can get to the rest of the bosses, i would recommend trying him once a week, if you can get close to killing him then try again, and if not then ask a friend to help you and then finish the rest of the raid on your own